# How can I bind an eventhandler to a class method in typescript?

Tags: jquery, events, typescript, binding

I write an app using typescript. And compile it to js, it works well except for the event binding part. _stateService is a class I injected into this class.

The following class is try to create a DOM element using jQuery, then pass  it to another class to render, the creating part works well and it renders finally on the page. But the event binding is somehow tricky.

At first, I want to use $().click() to bind, but failed since the element hasn't been rendered yet.

Then I try to use the $().on() to bind, it works. but at runtime, it throws an error:

> TemplatingService.ts:37 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'CallBack' of undefined(anonymous function) @
>   TemplatingService.ts:37dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3q.handle @
>   jquery.min.js:3

It seems that if I just use console.log("test") inside that bind function, it works. But if I try to bind it to a class method, it failed. Seems lost context, how Can I fix this?

The original typescript is:

```
export class TemplatingService implements ITemplatingService {
    _stateService: IStateService;

    constructor(stateService: IStateService) {
        this._stateService = stateService;
    }

    createPage(page:IPage):JQuery{
        let outerDiv = this.createLayout();
        for (let element of page.rawLayout){
            switch(element.type){
                case "button":
                    let temp = this.createJQueryButton();
                    $(".emulator").on('click', "#"+element.name, function(){
                                   this._stateService.CallBack(element);
                    });
                    outerDiv.append(temp);
                    break;
            }
        }
        return outerDiv;
    }
}
```

The related generating js is like the following:

```
"use strict";
var TemplatingService = (function () {
    function TemplatingService(stateService) {
        this._stateService = stateService;
    }

    TemplatingService.prototype.createPage = function (page) {
        var outerDiv = this.createLayout();
        var _loop_1 = function(element1) {
            switch (element.type) {
                case "button":
                    var temp = this_1.createjQueryButton();
                    $(".emulator").on('click', "#" + element.name, function () {
                        this._stateService.CallBack(element);
                    });
                    outerDiv.append(temp);
                    break;
            }
        };
        var this_1 = this;
       for (var _a = 0, _b = page.rawLayout; _a < _b.length; _a++) {
            var element1 = _b[_a];
            _loop_1(element1);
        }
        return outerDiv;

}());

exports.TemplatingService = TemplatingService;
//# sourceMappingURL=TemplatingService.js.map
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to bind `this` for callback.

```
 $(".emulator").on('click', "#"+element.name, function(){
     this._stateService.CallBack(element);
 }.bind(this));
```

or a better solution is to save `this` to a variable

```
createPage(page:IPage):JQuery{
    const self = this;
    let outerDiv = this.createLayout();
    for (let element of page.rawLayout){
        switch(element.type){
            case "button":
                let temp = this.createJQueryButton();
                $(".emulator").on('click', "#"+element.name, function(){
                     self._stateService.CallBack(element);
                });
                outerDiv.append(temp);
                break;
        }
    }
    return outerDiv;
}
```

Comment: You are my angel!!

Comment: Or even better: use arrow functions.

Comment: @MattiasBuelens Hi, thanks for the comment. When you refer arrow function, which method do you point? that stateService.CallBack() or the this.createPage()?

Comment: @AlbertGao as Mattias says, use arrow functions. I think it's a best choise here as you use TypeScript  :)

Comment: @AlbertGao the callback for click: `$(".emulator").on('click', "#"+element.name, () => {
                     this._stateService.CallBack(element);
                });`

Comment: I use the arrow function to redeclare stateService.CallBack() before asking, but doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is indeed that the function you're passing to `.on` has its own `this` context. With plain ES5, you can use `.bind(this)` or `var self = this;` to "fix" the `this` context, but with TypeScript and ES6 you can also use arrow functions:

```
export class TemplatingService implements ITemplatingService {
    _stateService: IStateService;

    constructor(stateService: IStateService) {
        this._stateService = stateService;
    }

    createPage(page:IPage):JQuery{
        let outerDiv = this.createLayout();
        for (let element of page.rawLayout){
            switch(element.type){
                case "button":
                    let temp = this.createJQueryButton();
                    $(".emulator").on('click', "#"+element.name, () => { // <<< arrow!
                                   this._stateService.CallBack(element);
                    });
                    outerDiv.append(temp);
                    break;
            }
        }
        return outerDiv;
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer. doesn't the arrow function just a simple anonymous function? If it is a function, why does it has a different behaviour than the original one?

Comment: @AlbertGao Arrow functions are not just shorter syntax for anonymous functions. They do not have their own `this` context, rather they "capture" the `this` context from the surrounding scope ([the "lexical `this`"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Lexical_this)). If you look at what the TypeScript compiler generates for this code, you'll see that it's equivalent to the `var self = this;` trick.

Comment: Thanks, now I know why 